# Why does ion-input display a second 1-pixel-wide text field?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In the signin page of my ionic 2 app, I have the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="signinForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="formItem">
            <ion-input #username type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" autocapitalize="off"></ion-input>
    </div>
</form>
```

This produces a weird [1-pixel-wide artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHOqw.png).

Here is what it produces on the page:

```
<div class="formItem">
    <ion-input formcontrolname="agencyNumber" placeholder="Agency ID" type="text" class="input input-md ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="agencyNumber" ng-reflect-placeholder="Agency ID" ng-reflect-type="text">
        <input class="text-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid text-input-md" formcontrolname="agencyNumber" placeholder="Agency ID" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" ng-reflect-klass="text-input" ng-reflect-ng-class="text-input-md" ng-reflect-model="test9994" ng-reflect-type="text" type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="Agency ID">
        <!--template bindings={
        "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
        }-->
        <input aria-hidden="true" next-input="" ng-reflect-type="text" type="text">
        <button class="text-input-clear-icon disable-hover button button-md button-clear button-clear-md" clear="" ion-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-hidden="true" hidden="">
            <span class="button-inner"></span>
            <div class="button-effect"></div>
        </button><!--template bindings={
        "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
        }-->
        <div class="input-cover" tappable=""></div>
   </ion-input>
</div>
```

That weird little artifact appears to be the second input field:

```
<input aria-hidden="true" next-input="" ng-reflect-type="text" type="text">
```

What is this? Why is it appearing?

EDIT: I have updated to ionic 2.0.0 with latest supported dependencies, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe thats from a validator from your FormBuilder. It is supposed to  turn red and underline the field if you fill it out and happens to be invalid. You should be able to remove it by editing the ng-valid and ng-invalid classes and making

Comment: How would I do this? I am not explicitly using ng-valid or ng-invalid anywhere in the actual code.

Comment: typically angular adds those classes onto your elements with formControlName implementing the FormBuilder. Look in the inspector tools to see what classes they have and modify them to see if it changes. It very well may not be the validations causing that issue, but in my past, that's what was doing it. If that is the case, you can either enter the styles into your .ts file or into the root styles.scss file in the /app directory

Comment: Okay, I've messed about with the elements with chrome remote devices debugging while it's running on android (the problem doesn't present while running in the browser from `ionic serve`), and it looks like the artifact has an attribute `aria-hidden="true"`, which obviously isn't hiding it. If I change it to simply `hidden="true"`, then it disappears. [This](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9159) seems related, but their solution doesn't work for me.